# How to convert uuid v4 of php into two 64 bit integers

Tags: php, uuid

Example: 
Uuid generated from v4 of php : 
`8bc278cb-2fb6-413b-add6-8ba39bf830e8`

I want to convert this into two 64 bit integers.

I've tried using `hexdec` of php but it's return value is of numbers. I want datatype integer.

Interestingly :

I have tried using hexdec with the above uuid and used this output to dechex. Some how, not getting the same value?

Any insights into this will be appreciated.

Comment: Random UUID (v4) has 2^122 combinations in total. While 64bit integer has, well, 2^64 combinations. It doesn't seems possible for the later to contain all possible data in the prior one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

UUID is a 128bit data type. Excluding the 6 reserved bits, there are 122 data bits in it. Makes it impossible to fully convert any UUID to a 64bit integer. You'll at least need to store it as 2 64bit numbers or 4 32bit numbers.

You can unpack the UUID into binary, then unpack it as 4 32bit unsigned character:

```
function uuidToHex($uuid) {
    return str_replace('-', '', $uuid);
}

function hexToUuid($hex) {
    $regex = '/^([\da-f]{8})([\da-f]{4})([\da-f]{4})([\da-f]{4})([\da-f]{12})$/';
    return preg_match($regex, $hex, $matches) ?
        "{$matches[1]}-{$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}-{$matches[4]}-{$matches[5]}" :
        FALSE;
}

function hexToIntegers($hex) {
    $bin = pack('h*', $hex);
    return unpack('L*', $bin);
}

function integersToHex($integers) {
    $args = $integers; $args[0] = 'L*'; ksort($args);
    $bin = call_user_func_array('pack', $args);
    $results = unpack('h*', $bin);
    return $results[1];
}

$uuid = '1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270';
var_dump($uuid);

$integers = hexToIntegers(uuidToHex('1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270'));
var_dump($integers);

$uuid = hexToUuid(integersToHex($integers));
var_dump($uuid);
```

It will returns

```
string(36) "1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270"
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(2764998289)
  [2]=>
  int(4245764002)
  [3]=>
  int(268479657)
  [4]=>
  int(120222434)
}
string(36) "1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270"
```

`$integers` is an array 4 32bit numbers that represents the hex.

#### Reference

1. Stack Overflow: [16 bytes binary form of canonical uuid representation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484267/16-bytes-binary-form-of-canonical-uuid-representation-in-php)
2. Stack Overflow: [How to convert byte array to integer in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683833/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-integer-in-php)
3. PHP Manual: [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

Comment: I have tried re-forming the hex from the two 64 bit integers that your function returns. It's not matching ```1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270```. Ideally it should match.

Comment: Can you show me the code you use to re-format the 2 64bit integer into hex?

Answer (score 3):

While it's common in other languages ([like Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) to get the least significant and most significant bits of a UUID as two unsigned 64-bit integers, PHP has trouble with this because all integers in PHP are signed. Even if using a 64-bit build of PHP, you will run into integer overflows when trying to get a real integer value of the least or most significant bits of a UUID.

The maximum integer value on 64-bit PHP is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, while an unsigned 64-bit integer has a max value of `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`. A UUID as two 64-bit integers needs to support values up to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`.

As an earlier answer mentioned, it might be better to split up the UUID into four unsigned 32-bit integers, if you need to split it up like that. (The max value of an unsigned 32-bit integer is `4,294,967,295`, which 64-bit PHP can support.)

If you're simply interested in storing a UUID in a more optimized way, you can convert it to a 16-byte binary string:

```
$uuid = '1968ec4a-2a73-11df-9aca-00012e27a270';

$binaryUuid = hex2bin(str_replace('-', '', $uuid));
```